# How to rewrite query to avoid logging as log_queries_not_using_indexes

Tags: mysql, logging, stored-procedures, indexing

I have following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc(IN p_idProject INTEGER)
BEGIN
DECLARE nowTime DATETIME;
SET @nowTime = NOW();

     SELECT 
         idCustomer 
     FROM NextCalls WHERE @nowTime-nextCall = 
         (SELECT MAX(@nowTime - nextCall) 
          FROM NextCalls 
          WHERE idProject = p_idProject AND nextCall < @nowTime) 
     LIMIT 1;
END $$
```

There is index set on `nextCall` column. Unfortunately it's being logged into `mysql-slow.log` file as a query that is not using indexes properly. This procedure is used very, very often and I would be really happy to avoid bad indexing. Is it possible to rewrite to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just selecting the oldest nextCall. There is no need to perform any calculations, you can just use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT idCustomer 
FROM NextCalls 
WHERE idProject = p_idProject AND nextCall < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY nextCall
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I got to be blind - so obvious solution :) Thx. BTW - you forgot `E` in `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Corrected current_timestamp. Finding the simplest solution is usually not easy. :)